# homebrew installed librdkafka to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ instead of /usr/local/Cellar/

Tags: install, homebrew, path

I'm on Mac Monterey (Apple cpu) and I've installed librdkafka:

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka

using homebrew. It has installed to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/librdkafka/`

However, online sources suggest the default installation path on ARM (which Apple M1 is?) should be `/usr/local/Cellar`

Because of this I get compiler errors that our makefile/compilation cannot find the librdkafka header. I assume Homebrew should have installed to `/usr/local/Cellar`?

What has caused this problem/how can i fix the default installation path and how can I fix the librdkafka installation path?

Answer (score 4):

Homebrew uses different destination folders for different architectures (see https://docs.brew.sh/Installation for details). In short, `/usr/local` is for Intel, `/opt/homebrew` for Apple Silicon (yes, it is ARM).

As for your makefile - you will likely have to adjust the following environment variables to the proper location. See [here](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040867082/en) for some details, but you likely can use this (you may need to adjust the version depending on what is installed, v1.8.2 is current today, 1/26/22:

`C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/librdkafka/1.8.2/include`

`LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/librdkafka/1.8.2/lib`